# grpc java bi-directional streaming - getting stream timeout runtimeexception occasionally

Tags: java, kubernetes-ingress, grpc-java

I have a java based grpc bi-di solution, my app is a middleware, when i'm streaming the rpc requests to the server, I get runtimeexception stream timeout followed by GO_AWAY messages and after that, the connection to the server is broken - no further requests reach the server. I have to restart my client for the rpc requests to start flowing again.

I have configured keepalivewithoutcalls on the Channel and also setting the deadlineafter parameter. But still I get the stream timeout.

My app is deployed on kubernetes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stream timeout"? Can you post the error you received?

Comment: What language is server side? Is there a proxy between client and server?